# Ошибка в задаче по поиску суммы цифр числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите, где я ошиблась?

Приложила скрин задания.
[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу код в своем редакторе на компьютере, выдает верный ответ. Переношу его в редактор в курсе и выдает ошибку. Помогите разобраться.

**Мой код:**

```
n = int(input()) #1

nn = 11//n

nnn = 111//n

print(n + nn + nnn)
```

**Ошибка:**

> Failed test #2 of 9. Wrong answer
>
> This is a sample test from the problem statement!

Test input:

```
2
```

Correct output:

```
246
```

Your code output:

```
62
```

Редактор на компьютере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот код не может выдавать правильный ответ ни в "редакторе на компьютере", ни где либо еще, потому что он делает совсем не то, что требуется. А то, что он выдает нужный ответ для 1 - просто случайность. Ведь и стоящие часы дважды в сутки показывают правильное время.

Comment: @Эникейщик, тогда совершенно не понимаю суть этого кода. Я же разделила 11 на 1 = 11 и 111/1 = 111. И потом просто сложила 1+11+111. Так в чем ошибка? Я не понимаю?

Comment: А где в задании говорится про "разделить"?

Comment: @Эникейщик, в задании конкретно нигде, но там же не говорится о том, что делить нельзя. Это задание можно решить и 123*1 . И у многих это работает, хотя в задании и об умножении тоже речи не идет

Comment: ну примените еще интеграл, раз нигде не говорится, что его применять нельзя :) Для чего вы вообще делите? Как это связано с заданием? Вы поняли, что там надо сделать?

Comment: @Эникейщик, думаю да. Получить цифры "1" "11" и "111" и сложить их, чтобы получилось число 123

Comment: Не совсем. Почему нужно получить именно 11 и 111?

Comment: Вот это трэш так трэш!

Comment: @LittlePrince Название задачи то прочитайте. Там написано, что нужно `n` размножать, а не единицы )

Comment: @CrazyElf, на следующий день все стало ясно)  Утро вечера мудренее)))

Answer (score 1):

Самое очевидное решение - сначала подготовить числа, стоящие из цифры `n`, а потом просто сложить их:

```
n = input()

ans = int(n) + int(n*2) + int(n*3)

print(ans)
```

Однако такое решение привязано к языку, а задача, скорее всего в том, чтобы разработать универсальный алгоритм:

```
n = int(input())

first_num = 10*n + n
second_num = 100*n + first_num

ans = n + first_num + second_num

print(ans)
```

Это решение "в лоб", где расписано каждое действие. Если немного подумать, какие действия мы совершаем, получим решение в одну строчку:

```
n = int(input())

ans = n*3 + n*20 + n*100

print(ans)
```

Comment: print(int(input()) * 123) ?

Comment: @rotabor, в идеале да